# Appropriate to call editor of journal where my name was removed as author?

Tags: ethics, etiquette, authorship

Unfortunately, I recently discovered that my name was removed from a published piece which I contributed substantially to (it is available online). I have already asked my co-authors, and all of them claim that they did not make the attempt to remove me as author.

Should I call the editor to clarify? I've already sent an e-mail but there has been no response so far. I have the relevant phone numbers as they are from my institution. I would note that I had zero notice that my name was removed; I only discovered this when referencing the work for another paper.

Comment: Have you tried asking your other co-authors first? It seems like they should be the first to bring this to, as normally editors are not adding or removing authors.

Comment: Hi, I have indeed contacted my other co-authors. All of them claimed that they did not make any attempt to remove my name from the piece.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have edited the question to include it.

Comment: Is the first author in the same department as you? it seems you need to escalate the issue internally, the editors have not such power.

Comment: As mentioned, all the authors, including the first author, claimed that they did not remove me as co-author. In fact, the first person I contacted was the first author.

Comment: Yes, the next step is to make direct contact with the editor and or journal. Bring your relevant work, take notes of what occurs in the meeting, time and date, Clearly state your case. If they do not correct the error, you then can turn to legal measures.

Comment: Contrary to all the people here, I suspect foul play from your co-author(s). So my questions. Are they in your department? in your university? what is your link to them? 
I may be wrong, and it may simply be a typesetting issue, however it seems a tad too big to happen.

Comment: Update: Editor of journal claimed that manuscript was submitted without my name. It has been since corrected but henceforth, I will not be working with any of the co-authors on future work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's appropriate, since it's a pretty major issue.

Something might have gone wrong in typesetting, in which case a corrigendum is probable.

Comment: Update: Editor of journal claimed that manuscript was submitted without my name. It has been since corrected but henceforth, I will not be working with any of the co-authors on future work.

Answer (score 5):

While a phone call might be needed to jolt them into action, you also need to send an email detailing the problem with appropriate links to the paper, along with its title and other information.

Spell out the problem in detail. Email is better for this than a "call", but an email alone might not be sufficient.

But it is difficult to communicate the detail in a phone call alone. But you could send the email and then follow up in a couple of days with a call.

Be specific and ask for a reply.